# Unable to Install Prism in Visual Studio 2013 Silverlight 5 Nevigation Application

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-2013, prism, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to install Prism in Visual Studio 2013 Professional. but getting following Error

```
    Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

enter code here`Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.50313.46

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package Prism
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.Composition (≥ 5.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'CommonServiceLocator (≥ 1.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.Interactivity (≥ 5.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.PubSubEvents (≥ 1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.Mvvm (≥ 1.0)'.
Installing 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2'.
Successfully installed 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2'.
Installing 'Prism.Composition 5.0.0'.
You are downloading Prism.Composition from Microsoft patterns & practices, the license agreement to which is available at http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/license. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Prism.Composition 5.0.0'.
Installing 'Prism.Interactivity 5.0.0'.
You are downloading Prism.Interactivity from Microsoft patterns & practices, the license agreement to which is available at http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/license. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Prism.Interactivity 5.0.0'.
Installing 'Prism.PubSubEvents 1.0.0'.
You are downloading Prism.PubSubEvents from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/license. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Prism.PubSubEvents 1.0.0'.
Installing 'Prism.Mvvm 1.0.0'.
You are downloading Prism.Mvvm from Microsoft patterns & practices, the license agreement to which is available at https://pnpmvvm.codeplex.com/license. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Prism.Mvvm 1.0.0'.
Installing 'Prism 5.0.0'.
You are downloading Prism from Microsoft patterns & practices, the license agreement to which is available at http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/license. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Prism 5.0.0'.
Adding 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Successfully added 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Adding 'Prism.Composition 5.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Successfully added 'Prism.Composition 5.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Adding 'Prism.Interactivity 5.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Successfully added 'Prism.Interactivity 5.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Adding 'Prism.PubSubEvents 1.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Successfully added 'Prism.PubSubEvents 1.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Adding 'Prism.Mvvm 1.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Successfully added 'Prism.Mvvm 1.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Adding 'Prism 5.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.
Successfully added 'Prism 5.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.Web.

PM> Install-Package Prism
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.Composition (≥ 5.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'CommonServiceLocator (≥ 1.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.Interactivity (≥ 5.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.PubSubEvents (≥ 1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Prism.Mvvm (≥ 1.0)'.
'Prism 5.0.0' already installed.
Adding 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2' to Hpmsprsim.
Successfully added 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2' to Hpmsprsim.
Adding 'Prism.Composition 5.0.0' to Hpmsprsim.
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Prism.Composition 5.0.0'. You are trying to install this
 package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any
 assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Prism
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackage 
   Command

PM>
```

I have Silverlight 5 installed in my system.  And I created 1 silverlight 5 Nevigation Project on VS2013. When i try installing Prism in this project by Nuget Package it is giving me following error.
Please guide me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256611/errors-with-installing-prism-in-visual-studio sys you can't install with 4.5 so I tried with 4.5.1 still same issue. so I did with my abstest.Web project it got install but I see all Prism dlls except Microsoft.Practice.Prism it contains M...Pr...Prism.Composite. As it got install into so I Tried giving reference to abstest project. during Add it says it has  been build against Silverlight. Is it mean there is no Prism for Silverlight 5?

Comment: When I downloaded Prism 4.1 it is allows me to add. Is it the the version which will work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism 5 is not compatible for Silverlight 5 so I used Prism 4.1.

How I did?

I created a Silverlight 5 Application via these steps.

1. Create a folder D/PrismTrial/Scr , D/PrismTrial/Libs ,D/PrismTrial/Scr/Modules ,D/PrismTrial/Scr/business
2. Copy Prism 4.1 dll in Libs
3. Create a Silverlight Application Project in Src Folder. provides 2 Project Abs and Abs.Web
4. Provide dll Refrence to Abs Project

   ```
   Microsoft.Practices.Prism
   Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions
   Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity
   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight
   ```
5. Create a Bootstrapper.cs class
6. Remove Main.xmal & Create Shell.xaml
7. Create Mouldes in D/PrismTrial/Scr/Modules Like : Abs.Auth , Abs.TabTest
8. Loaded these Modules in Bootstrapper.
9. With Each And Every Step I tested. It worked.

I followed 
http://www.silverlightshow.net/video/WCF-RIA-Services-Webinar-5.aspx and few Prim Documentation from msdn. http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/ Error started from here and set my scope with Prism 4.1.

I'll shortly Upload my test project to some open repository. any free storage let me know.